# referencing widgets from imported module

Tags: tkinter, attributeerror, nameerror

I have 2 TkInter modules. One is toolbar module (tBar.py) and the second is a general module (tBarCall.py).

1) the toolbar module (tBar.py): This will create a toolbar frame and place buttons (like save, add, delete etc.) on top of it.

2) the client master module (tBarCall.py): This will import and run the toolbar module. Then at a later stage it should enable / disable some of the buttons placed on the toolbar frame. Please see the errors I am shown when I am trying to enable/ disable the buttons.

I am able to import the toolbar module from inside the client master module, but I am not able to enable/ disable (reference) the buttons on the toolbar frame.

Can you please help me how I can do this?

Here is the code:

===tBar.py===

```
import tkinter as tk

def attach_toolbar(rootWindow, action, save_record, first_record):
    if action == "I":
        fToolbar = tk.Frame(rootWindow, padx = 1, pady = 1, bg="RED")
        fToolbar.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky='w') #pack(anchor="nw",expand=1) #
        bSave = tk.Button(fToolbar, text="save", command=save_record)     #width=6, height=2, text = "Save\nrecord", font=("Calibri", 8), 
        bFirst = tk.Button(fToolbar, text="first", command=first_record)     #width=6, height=2, text = "First\nrecord", font=("Calibri", 8), 

        bSave.pack(side="left")
        bFirst.pack(side="left")
    else:
        bFirst.configure(state="disabled")
```

===tBarCall.py===

```
import tkinter as tk
import tBar

def save_record():
    print ("save_record")

def first_record():
    print ("first_record")

class startModule:
    def __init__(self, rootWindow):
        print("__init__")

        self.rootWindow = rootWindow
        self.rootClient = tk.Toplevel(self.rootWindow)
        self.rootClient.geometry('1300x650+1+1')
        tBar.attach_toolbar(self.rootClient, "I", save_record, first_record)
        #tBar.attach_toolbar(self.rootClient, "D", save_record, first_record) #UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bFirst' referenced before assignment
        #bFirst.configure(state="disabled") #NameError: name 'bFirst' is not defined        
        #self.rootClient.bFirst.configure(state="disabled") #AttributeError: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'bFirst'
        #self.rootClient.fToolbar.bFirst.configure(state="disabled") #AttributeError: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'fToolbar'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    startModule(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[Errorscr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuSf6.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround. I used a DICTionary in the toolbar module (i.e. tBarCall.py) to store the details of the buttons save, add, delete etc. Then I returned this dictionary to the calling module i.e. tBarCall.py. Now, I can disable the buttons using this dictionary. Following is the additional coding I did:

tBar.py

```
retButtonIdentifier = {"bSave" : bSave}
retButtonIdentifier["bFirst"]=bFirst    

return retButtonIdentifier
```

tBarCall.py

```
self.dictButtonIdentifier = tBar.attach_toolbar(self.rootClient, "I", save_record, first_record)

self.dictButtonIdentifier["bSave"].configure(state="disabled")            
self.dictButtonIdentifier["bFirst"].configure(state="disabled")
```